# Changing github identifiers in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

I am working on a project shared through github and eclipse, and I can commit without problems, my partner however, entered the wrong identifiers(username and password) the first time he remote pushed. Thus, every time he tries to push and commit on the repository, eclipse uses those wrong identifiers to log to github and it fails. Is there a way to change those identifiers?

Answer (score 1):

If he entered the wrong username, he can go on `Window/Preferences/` search for `git` and on `Configuration` section, he can change this.
Otherwise if entered the wrong password, he can search for `secure` and on the `Secure storage` section, on `Contents` tab, he can change the password on git section